# Positioning the child of View in React Native

Tags: user-interface, react-native

I was creating a view using react native where the following should be the outcome.

[image: Actual View]

But it's coming as follows :

[image: Outcome]

The corresponding code is as follows :

```
<View style={{marginBottom: 40, marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 16, alignItems: "center"}}>
                    <View>    
                        <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name='wallet' size={24}/>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16}}>Wallet</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 32, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4}}>{`Available Balance \u20B9 200`}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{marginTop: 10}}>    
                        <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name='credit-card' size={24}/>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16}}>Card</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 32, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4}}>XXXXXX 1235</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

I ma just copy pasting the 1st child view to make to second in the main View. Why then the positioning is incorrect in this scenario ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: rid alignItems from the main container, if you want it center put inner flexDirection row style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of not giving the fixed width to the view and the due to the text length.

> ```
>     <View style={{ marginBottom: 40, marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 16, alignItems: "center" }}>
>       <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
>         <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
>           <Icon name='wallet' size={24} />
>           <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16 }}>Wallet</Text>
>         </View>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 32, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4 }}>{`Available Balance \u20B9 200`}</Text>
>       </View>
>       <View style={{ marginTop: 10, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
>         <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
>           <Icon name='wallet' size={24} />
>           <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16 }}>Card</Text>
>         </View>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 32, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4 }}>XXXXXX 1235 dfasdfasdfas</Text>
>       </View>
>     </View>
> ```

This will be the output of the above code I write more text.

[image]

Answer:

So if you give the fixed width to the view like:

> ```
>     <View style={{ marginBottom: 40, marginHorizontal: 30, marginTop: 16, alignItems: "center" }}>
>       <View style={{ width:'50%' }}>
>         <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
>           <Icon name='wallet' size={24} />
>           <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16 }}>Wallet</Text>
>         </View>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 16, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4 }}>{`Available Balance \u20B9 200`}</Text>
>       </View>
>       <View style={{ marginTop: 10,  width:'50%' }}>
>         <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
>           <Icon name='wallet' size={24} />
>           <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, marginLeft: 16 }}>Card</Text>
>         </View>
>         <Text style={{ fontSize: 12, marginLeft: 16, alignSelf: "center", marginTop: 4 }}>XXXXXX 1235</Text>
>       </View>
>     </View>
> ```

The Output will be this:

[image]

Comment: Perfect !, Thanks for the answer :) But if you see that in the main pic the icon is parallel to both the lines. (both for wallet and card) That is actually not maintained in this solution.

Comment: You checked the last image and also write the code and check it is parallel bro. If you like my code and help you can make my day ;) thank you bro